# how to redirect to a gsp page( grails)?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have somme trouble in my app.
there are two domain classes :
1st named patient
2nd named antecedants

When i show a patient ,instance of antecedants is displayed.
when i click it it goes to the antecedants view/show .
the delete button  below is clickable

```
 <g:if test="${patientInstance.antecedant == null}">
            <li ><g:link  class="create" params="[id: patientInstance.id]" controller="Antecedants" action="create" id="${this.id }">Saisir les antecedants</g:link>  </li>
            </g:if>
```

so when i do, i sent a parameter within a g:link to the antecedants controller named num (for test) , all of this to get back to the patient it all began with:

```
redirect (uri: "/patient/show/${y}")
```

And that's where the issue comes , when i run it and go to the view/antecedant/1 and i click on delete ,it takes me to an 405 error page .description :The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

```
    def y=params.num
    antecedantsInstance.delete flush:true
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you send propably a delete http method or is your action declared by a allowed method that is not the same that you sent?? If you do this, you have to add a method declaration to your action in the controller. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html

Comment: i still don't find a way to do it ,by the way i'm a noob in grails , so please make it just a litle bit more clear or ask me what you need to to know more than it's says below. thanks again.